# Iphone How do I get ID and owner into NString from this json HASH

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, json, flickr

Iphone How do I get ID and owner into NString from this hash.

```
  { "photos": { "page": 1, "pages": 26, "perpage": 10, "total": "259", 
        "photo": [
          { "id": "8493465829", "owner": "77009896@N08", "secret": "e0a8381648", "server": "8367", "farm": 9, "title": "IMG_9444", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
          { "id": "8494565062", "owner": "77009896@N08", "secret": "6aaa0f41b9", "server": "8372", "farm": 9, "title": "IMG_9443", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
          { "id": "8493492761", "owner": "77009896@N08", "secret": "30f4da89b4", "server": "8523", "farm": 9, "title": "IMG_9488", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
          { "id": "8493492007", "owner": "77009896@N08", "secret": "95c0f2215e", "server": "8529", "farm": 9, "title": "IMG_9487", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
          { "id": "8493471375", "owner": "77009896@N08", "secret": "812fddc8cd", "server": "8516", "farm": 9, "title": "IMG_9453", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
          { "id": "8493463059", "owner": "77009896@N08", "secret": "7eedfd6b7c", "server": "8389", "farm": 9, "title": "IMG_9440", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
          { "id": "8494572044", "owner": "77009896@N08", "secret": "e4d514021d", "server": "8087", "farm": 9, "title": "IMG_9454", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
          { "id": "8493462429", "owner": "77009896@N08", "secret": "43822f14a5", "server": "8526", "farm": 9, "title": "IMG_9439", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
          { "id": "8493489419", "owner": "77009896@N08", "secret": "8b50906ebe", "server": "8515", "farm": 9, "title": "IMG_9480", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
          { "id": "8493488459", "owner": "77009896@N08", "secret": "7ec696b8d0", "server": "8242", "farm": 9, "title": "IMG_9479", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 }
        ] }, "stat": "ok" }
```

This code is giving me an error

```
NSDictionary *photos =[JSON objectForKey:@"photos"];
NSDictionary *picturesOfLocations = photos[@"photo"];

NSString *flickUserID = picturesOfLocations[@"id"];

// NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[picturesOfLocations objectForKey:@"photo"]];
//NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
// cell.imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
NSLog(@"%@", flickUserID);
```

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7527430'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1ce3012 0x1120e7e 0x1d6e4bd 0x1cd2bbc 0x1cd294e 0x24dd9 0x171f2 0x185b9 0x4a4753f 0x4a59014 0x4a497d5 0x1c89af5 0x1c88f44 0x1c88e1b 0x1c3d7e3 0x1c3d668 0x64ffc 0x244d 0x2375)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception`

I got the same error when trying the following

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {



NSDictionary* dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSON options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSString* stringPhoho = [[[[dict valueForKey:@"photos"] valueForKey:@"photo"] objectForKey:0] valueForKey:@"owner"];
NSLog(@"%@",stringPhoho);
```

Comment: is this work with other keys ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *picturesOfLocations = photos[@"photo"];
```

is wrong because it is a NSArray ( [ ) so :

```
NSArray *picturesOfLocations = photos[@"photo"];
```

At the end you have a NSArray of NSDictionary and you can use :

```
//parse each photo
for (NSDictionary * photo in picturesOfLocations ){
     NSString* flickUserID = [photo  objectForKey:@"id"];
     NSLog(@"%@", flickUserID);
    //etc...
}
```

Comment: when i call NSLog(@"%@",picturesOfLocations); null is called. And that for loop doesn't get called.

Comment: You have to change it like this `NSArray *picturesOfLocations = [photos objectForKey:@"photo"];`

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following syntax

Use JSOn serialization as bellow

```
NSDictionary* dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

and parse `owner` as bellow

```
NSString* stringPhoho = [[[[dictResponse valueForKey:@"photos"] valueForKey:@"photo"] objectForKey:0] valueForKey:@"owner"];
```

it will give you `owner` `77009896@N08` which is situated at `index` `0` on array of `photo`

you can access all 'owner' id as per your requirements i.e using for loop, if you are using tableview then using `didSelectRow` method, using button tag etc...

Comment: I got the same error when trying the following                                        NSDictionary* dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSON options:kNilOptions error:nil];
        NSString* stringPhoho = [[[[dict valueForKey:@"photos"] valueForKey:@"photo"] objectForKey:0] valueForKey:@"owner"];
         NSLog(@"%@",stringPhoho);

Answer (score 0):

photos[@"photo"] gives the error I think ....

It should be something like

... = [photos objectForKey:@"photo"];

see class reference of NSDictionary!

Comment: well same goes for the other two cases where you use a string as array index (inside [])

Answer (score 0):

'photo' is an array of dictionaries, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

"photo" tag is an array of dictionaries. I haven't tried this, but thinks this should work for you.

```
NSDictionary *photos =[JSON objectForKey:@"photos"];
NSArray *picturesOfLocations = [photos objectForKey:@"photo"];

for(NSDictionary* pic in  picturesOfLocations )
{
   NSString *flickUserID = [pic objectForKey:@"id"] 
}
```